# How to prove that $ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, sequence-of-function

I was doing some practice problems for limits and I encountered the following problem:

> Does $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$ exist, if so find the limit as a function of $x$.

I tried plugging in some constant values for $x$ and found that the limits all converge to $0$. My hypothesis is that the limit of this expression as $n$ approaches infinity is indeed $0$, but how can I prove this?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try the ratio test?

Comment: Hint: Try to show that for a fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there exist $C>0, 0<\alpha<1$ such that $\frac{|x|^n}{n!}\leq C\alpha^n$ for large enough $n$